# Echarts - properly optimise plotting hundreds/thousands series in 2D scatter/line chart

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

I am trying to plot a large data set containing hundreds/thousands of series with Echarts, but the resulting plot is very slow and difficult to work with.

Here is an example code that you can try in Echarts [webpage](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-stack&code=PTAEHEFMDtIJwIYBdKkdAJgewLagM7wCWk-AUGQG4JwHGkD6NiAnqALygDaAugNwUAZlloAKADaQkoIh1ABGPjIA88gAwalRANTaAlAG8KoUJOkZkCOV3kAaAEy2AzLYAstgKy2AbLYDsPAB0OAgADqKCAK7QAMZIRFjQogAeeqAGaFKRcNCgyaAAVKAAssgAFoHo2DiiekoAvnVkJs2mUnRwJHJGJibQCDiQAFygAOQAyvSj2kS2rSZILKHDY-JEsKNzvaAWSAgjuwit9QItJoSdjMwILIGhkfhlohckTfUUIKAAwmU00liheKJchkAFA3KcHqgeJISQjKELSDJJAjCZ7GIAa0gGFAABl1pBRscttCsFhxPFQvD5tDOgBzOnwVEIZJEfBEkz1EmSRmYanbQ4jLijACiISI4k2YwAqtAErkAIIYdm2MYANSIGEgWFASpVYwAIkQ4JA4lKJpAaDEyqARdA6QTRjxia06Z0MPzepJBCixk4AKSbGn0sq-0auQMkkwAIywSCQuFRAaD2xiiT261xCGjkHEIyQcEikBdCzJ4ljyU9JkElqQ2RWCN6-AQlEgCvwAEkQoz4e9tn3QFzWskFaz8FXoUsVqMYshIHSRCwU71Y9ELHAWOAwiNBAhxIQoztLELRsVEuaACpF80AdWxl7KkXNADFOubxsh39EnSXQCxR2yE6LMsqLUOI16_iYhwAFpkjgQo0o2CxTqi6z4JqhKHucexwL6ahYaAMAegoGg0kO2xIQQOF4QRREjOoahka0PAki8pAjGx-BMHArBkCcQA).

```js
// Generate random series

var series_array = [];

for (let i = 1; i<1000; i++){

  let data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7].map(function(x) { return x * Math.random(); });
  
  let serie = {
    name: 'Serie'+i,
    type: 'line',
    data: data
  };
  
  series_array.push(serie);
}

// Chart options

option = {
  title: {
    text: 'Stacked Line'
  },
  tooltip: {
    trigger: 'axis'
  },
  legend: {
    data: ['Email', 'Union Ads', 'Video Ads', 'Direct', 'Search Engine']
  },
  grid: {
    left: '3%',
    right: '4%',
    bottom: '3%',
    containLabel: true
  },
  toolbox: {
    feature: {
      saveAsImage: {}
    }
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'category',
    boundaryGap: false,
    data: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']
  },
  yAxis: {
    type: 'value'
  },
    dataZoom: [
    {
      type: 'inside',
      start: 0,
      end: 100
    },
    {
      start: 0,
      end: 100
    }
  ],
  series: series_array
};
```

I tried using [large](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-lines.large) and [progressive](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#graphic.elements-line.progressive), but they seem to work on single series and not on all series plotted.

How should I properly improve the performance of this type of chart?

Answer (score 0):

Echarts is not made to depict huge amounts of data. I would suggest you think about the way you want to present your data. Having thousands of lines in a chart is not very clear anyways. Maybe you can do some preprocessing and show higher order features or only show partial / filtered data at a time.

That beeing said there are some minor optimizations you can include:

1. Avoid everything that rerenders the chart at high frequency. In your given example I removed the dataZoom of type 'inside' and set the slider zooms [realtime](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#dataZoom-slider.realtime) attribute to false.
2. For line charts you can reduce the load from rerendering if you set `symbol: false`.

The given example only shows line series but since the title also mentions scatter series I will touch on them.

3. Set [large](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.large) and [largeThreshold](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.largeThreshold) for **each** series (only works for scatter). You can also set [progressiveThreshold](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-scatter.progressiveThreshold) to block the UI as little as possible while rendering.

If this is all not enough there is a special kind of scatter series for large amounts of data which makes use of WebGl: [ScatterGL](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option-gl.html#series-scatterGL)

Comment: I agree that presenting a lot of data is not that useful. Thank you for the recommendations, I will try them. In the scatter case, what Threshold values are good for large and progressive?

Comment: That depends on your data and you should try what works for you. If you have thousands of series with 100 datapoints each, a threshold larger than 100 would never be triggered. Also note, that when large optimization is enabled some features like visualmaps do not work anymore.